# Sound pressure levels off by certain dB

Tags: matlab

I'm analysing a large hyrophone data set in MATLAB using signal processing toolbox and I find when i do the PSD or Third octave band frequency levels, they levels in dB are offset by more than 30 or 40 dB. Can someone suggest what are the major or primary parameters that one needs to check for this. I did enter all ref pressure of water, system end to end senstivity and all correctly. If there is something I'm missing, I would like to know. please find below part of code

```
xgrid = buffer(xbit,N,ceil(N*r),'nodelay').'; %buffer function breaks data into segments or frames as set by user   
                                    %grid whose rows are each (overlapped) 
                                    %   segment for analysis
if xgrid(length(xgrid(:,1)),N) == 0 %remove final segment if not full
    xgrid = xgrid(1:length(xgrid(:,1))-1,:);
end

M = length(xgrid(:,1));             %total number of data segments

xgrid = xgrid.*repmat(w/alpha,M,1);%multiply segments by Hann window function



   %%computing DFT
    X = abs(fft(xgrid.')).'; %DFT of each segment

    %%computing power spectrum which is square of the amplitude
    P = (X./N).^2;

    %%Compute single-sided power spectrum 

    Pss = 2*P(:,2:floor(N/2)+1);        %

f = floor(fs/2)*linspace(1/(N/2),1,N/2);
                                    %calculate frequencies of DFT bins
flow = find(single(f) >= lcut,1,'first');   %low-frequency cut-off                                    
fhigh = find(single(f) <= hcut,1,'last');   %high-frequency cut-off
f = f(flow:fhigh);                  %frequency bins in user-defined range
nf = length(f);                     %number of frequency bins

%% Compute noise power bandwidth and delta(f)

B = (1/N).*(sum((w/alpha).^2));     %noise power bandwidth 
delf = fs/N;                                     

%% Converting to dB
    %for  PSD calculation
        APSD = 10*log10((1/(delf*B))*Pss(:,flow:fhigh)./(pref^2))-S;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please insert some code demonstrating exactly what you are doing. If the issue is a programming error, then somebody here can help spot the problem. If the issue a theoretical one, then Stackoverflow is not the place for this question

Comment: I added the code. thanks Bremen

Comment: I don't know this use case, but I would suggest two things you may want to double check: 1. Sometimes in FFT calculations, you are supposed to normalize by sqrt(N), sometimes by N, and sometimes by 1. Just make sure that you have that right. 2. Windowing will introduce some error in the results. I wouldn't expect it around the peaks, but if the signal to noise ratio is bad, then this might be the source of the discrepancy.

Comment: sure will check that. Thanks bremen_matt

Comment: Normalizing by N worked out to be just fine to get the right amplitudes. I thought the fft function in MATLAB would be taking care of that.

Comment: HI bremen_matt, we need to first do the DFT of each segment and then average them and normalize by dividing by N (as in the above code which is done to get Power spectrum P) so if I run this code as it is it is having huge amplitude values in the frequency domain. But if I divide X ( DFT of each segment) by N and then rest of the code doesnt change at all, thats when I'm getting the right amplitude values in frequency domain. SO my question is, is it right to divide X by N and then also repeat the same normalization of dividing by N again while computing P? thanks

Comment: I do not know enough about the field you are working to know what values you are seeking. But if you are getting the right result, then the answer appears to be yes